# How to segregate data from database according to condition?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
 public static DataSet getAvailableApartmentsPricesData(string userid, string password, string cityId, string date_from, string date_to, string no_of_people)
    { 
        bool res = validation(userid, password);
        string errormsg = string.Empty;
        DataSet ds7 = new DataSet();
        DataSet dsavailablity = new DataSet();
        if (res)
        {
            string partnerid = Getpartneridbyuid(userid, password);

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
            string withPriceQuery = "select distinct i.id_edificio ,ce.id_capacidad_edificio, i.precio , SUM(i.precio) as base_price, i.disponibilidad, ce.tipo, c.max_capacidad, c.descripcion_capacidad, e.poblacion_edificio, e.provincia_edificio, e.pais_edificio FROM inventario i, capacidad_edificio ce, capacidad c, edificios e WHERE 1=1 and (i.disponibilidad > '0' OR i.disponibilidad >= '-1') and i.fecha between '" + date_from + "' and Date_Sub('" + date_to + "',interval 1 Day) and i.id_capacidad_edificio = ce.id_capacidad_edificio and ce.id_capacidad = c.id_capacidad and c.max_capacidad >= '" + no_of_people + "' and i.id_edificio = e.id_edificio and e.poblacion_edificio = '" + cityId + "' and e.status = 'STATUS_ACTIVE' and e.xml = 'si' group by i.id_edificio, i.id_capacidad_edificio order by i.precio ASC";
            MySqlCommand cmd7 = new MySqlCommand(withPriceQuery, con);
            MySqlDataAdapter da7 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd7);
            da7.Fill(ds7);
            DataTable dt = ds7.Tables[0];

            //
            MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
            string withPriceQueryByAppforavialibity = "select distinct i.id_edificio ,ce.id_capacidad_edificio, i.precio , SUM(i.precio) as base_price, i.disponibilidad, ce.tipo, c.max_capacidad, c.descripcion_capacidad, e.poblacion_edificio, e.provincia_edificio, e.pais_edificio FROM inventario i, capacidad_edificio ce, capacidad c, edificios e WHERE 1=1 and ( i.disponibilidad = '-1') and i.fecha between '" + date_from + "' and Date_Sub('" + date_to + "',interval 1 Day) and i.id_capacidad_edificio = ce.id_capacidad_edificio and ce.id_capacidad = c.id_capacidad and c.max_capacidad >= '" + no_of_people + "' and i.id_edificio = e.id_edificio and e.poblacion_edificio = '" + cityId + "' and e.status = 'STATUS_ACTIVE' and e.xml = 'si' group by i.id_edificio, i.id_capacidad_edificio order by i.precio ASC";
            MySqlCommand cmdforavialibity = new MySqlCommand(withPriceQueryByAppforavialibity, con1);
            MySqlDataAdapter daforavialibity = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdforavialibity);
            daforavialibity.Fill(dsavailablity);
            DataTable dtvailablity = dsavailablity.Tables[0];

            if (ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                System.Data.DataColumn newColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn("descripcion_promocion");
                dt.Columns.Add(newColumn);

                System.Data.DataColumn newColumn1 = new System.Data.DataColumn("valor_promocion");
                dt.Columns.Add(newColumn1);

                System.Data.DataColumn newColumn2 = new System.Data.DataColumn("BestPrice");
                dt.Columns.Add(newColumn2);

                System.Data.DataColumn newColumn4 = new System.Data.DataColumn("id_promocion");
                dt.Columns.Add(newColumn4);

                System.Data.DataColumn newColumn3 = new System.Data.DataColumn("BookingType");
                dt.Columns.Add(newColumn3);

                System.Data.DataColumn newcolcondition = new System.Data.DataColumn("Condition");
                dt.Columns.Add(newcolcondition);

                System.Data.DataColumn newcolconditionmsg = new System.Data.DataColumn("ConditionMessage");
                dt.Columns.Add(newcolconditionmsg);

                for (int i = 0; i < ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataSet dscondition = GetConditionList(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id_edificio"].ToString(), ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["tipo"].ToString(), date_from, date_to);
                    if (dscondition.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                       // valor_condicion, c.valor_last_condicion
                        errormsg = Errormsg(dscondition.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tipo_condicion"].ToString(), date_to, date_from, dscondition.Tables[0].Rows[0]["valor_condicion"].ToString(), dscondition.Tables[0].Rows[0]["valor_last_condicion"].ToString(), dscondition.Tables[0].Rows[0]["parent_condition_id"].ToString());
                        dt.Rows[i]["Condition"] = "TRUE";
                        dt.Rows[i]["ConditionMessage"] = errormsg;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i]["Condition"] = "FALSE";
                        dt.Rows[i]["ConditionMessage"] = "No conditions Applicable";
                    }
                    //DataSet dsprice = price(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id_edificio"].ToString(), date_from, date_to, no_of_people, ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["tipo"].ToString());
                    string type = ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["tipo"].ToString();
                    DataSet dsprice = GetPromotionIds(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id_edificio"].ToString(), date_from, date_to, type);
                    if (dsprice.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i]["descripcion_promocion"] = 0.0;
                        dt.Rows[i]["valor_promocion"] = 0.0;
                        dt.Rows[i]["BestPrice"] = ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["base_price"];
                        dt.Rows[i]["id_promocion"] = "Null";
                        if (dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count == dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToInt16(dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"]) == -1)
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "On Request";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "Online";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt16(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"]) == -1)
                            {
                                dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "On Request";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "Online";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string description_promotion = string.Empty;
                        double best_price = 0.0;
                        for (int pro = 0; pro < dsprice.Tables[0].Rows.Count; pro++)
                        {


                            double unitprice = (Convert.ToDouble(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["precio"]));
                            double base_price = Convert.ToDouble(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["base_price"]);
                            double valor_promotion = Convert.ToDouble(dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["valor_promocion"]);
                            switch (dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["tipo_promocion"].ToString())
                            {
                                case "porcentaje":

                                    if (best_price != 0.0)
                                    {
                                        description_promotion = description_promotion +" + "+ dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["descripcion_promocion"].ToString();
                                        double val = ((best_price * valor_promotion) / 100);
                                        best_price = best_price - val;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        description_promotion = description_promotion + dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["descripcion_promocion"].ToString();
                                        double val1 = ((base_price * valor_promotion) / 100) - best_price;
                                        best_price = base_price - val1;
                                    }

                                    break;
                                case "descuento_dias":

                                    if (best_price != 0.0)
                                    {
                                        description_promotion = description_promotion +" + "+ dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["descripcion_promocion"].ToString();
                                        double val2 = best_price - (base_price - (unitprice * valor_promotion));
                                        best_price = val2;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        description_promotion = description_promotion + dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["descripcion_promocion"].ToString();
                                        best_price = (base_price - (unitprice * valor_promotion)) - best_price;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "fixed":

                                    if (best_price != 0.0)
                                    {
                                        description_promotion = description_promotion +" + "+ dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["descripcion_promocion"].ToString();
                                        double val3 = best_price - (base_price - valor_promotion);
                                        best_price = val3;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        description_promotion = description_promotion + dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[pro]["descripcion_promocion"].ToString();
                                        best_price = (base_price - valor_promotion) - best_price;
                                    }
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                        //   dt.Rows[i]["descripcion_promocion"] = Convert.ToString(dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[0]["descripcion_promocion"]);
                        dt.Rows[i]["descripcion_promocion"] = description_promotion;
                        dt.Rows[i]["valor_promocion"] = Convert.ToString(dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[0]["valor_promocion"]);
                        dt.Rows[i]["BestPrice"] = string.Format("{0:f2}", best_price);
                        dt.Rows[i]["id_promocion"] = Convert.ToString(dsprice.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id_promocion"]);
                        if (dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count == dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToInt16(dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"]) == -1)
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "On Request";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "Online";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt16(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"]) == -1)
                            {
                                dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "On Request";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dt.Rows[i]["BookingType"] = "Online";
                            }
                        }

                    }
               }
                ds7.AcceptChanges();
                return ds7;
            }
            else
            {
                return noDataFound();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return invalidLogin();
        }
    }
```

**database data**

```
id_edificio |id_capacidad |precio      |base_price|disponibilidad|tipo   |max_cap     |desc_cap  |pob_edi|pro_edi|pais_edi
1553    |   54  | 64.85 | 349.55     |   5         |  A     |4  |2/4    |8141      |19        |ES
1552    |   56  | 69.8  | 408.8  |   5         |   A    |4  |2/4    |8141      |19        |ES
2202    |   1834    | 89.9  | 538.7  |   3         |   A    |6  |4/6    |8141      |19        |ES
1551    |   60  | 99.4  | 695.8  |   3         |   A    |4  |2/4    |8141      |19        |ES
1986    |   1095    | 115.55    | 617.15     |  -1         |   A    |8  |6/8    |8141      |19        |ES
1986    |   1096    | 119.85    | 655.65     |  -1         |   B    |8  |8  |8141      |19        |ES
```

I have this data in my `getAvailableApartmentsPricesData()` function i need to display data and `disponibilidad` this column contains many values in that `-1` means `onRequest` and remaining values indicates `Online`, but in my `getAvailableApartmentsPricesData()` function taking everything online only its not segrate properly.and i have two set query in `getAvailableApartmentsPricesData()` function `1.ds7` `2.daforavialibity`. `1.ds7` contains above data and `2.daforavialibity` contains only `onRequested(-1)` data using both the query need to segrate data according to `disponibilidad` values and display pls help me out from this problem.

Comment: you wrote 1 long sentence and pasted a block of not so relevant code. Paste the sql and state expected result.

Comment: you got my question its mysql and i have written query also see

Answer (score 1):

This part of your first WHERE clause:
`(i.disponibilidad > '0' OR i.disponibilidad >= '-1')` 
means that the query will return all rows where i.disponibilidad = -1 or anything higher than that. The condition `i.disponibilidad > '0'` is not needed.

Also you are testing using mathemtic symbols such as '=' and '>' but you are wrapping the numbers in quotes so that they are being treated as string. e.g. -1 is a number '-1' is a string.

This part of your second WHERE clause:
`( i.disponibilidad = '-1')` 
also does the same thing

So...
daforavialibity should contain `( i.disponibilidad = -1)` in its query and da7 shouldn't have anything there at all assuming you want da7 to display all records.

I have tried to help  as much as possible here but your English is very hard to understand and I do not completely understand the problem, but reading between the lines I think this is what you are trying to get at.

**Modifications Following Comment**

Having had a chat with you in the comments section it appears that your column `i.disponibilidad` is an integer field and so your query needs to be changed. Please change this line:
`string withPriceQueryByAppforavialibity = "select distinct i.id_edificio ,ce.id_capacidad_edificio, i.precio , SUM(i.precio) as base_price, i.disponibilidad, ce.tipo, c.max_capacidad, c.descripcion_capacidad, e.poblacion_edificio, e.provincia_edificio, e.pais_edificio FROM inventario i, capacidad_edificio ce, capacidad c, edificios e WHERE 1=1 and ( i.disponibilidad = '-1') and i.fecha between '" + date_from + "' and Date_Sub('" + date_to + "',interval 1 Day) and i.id_capacidad_edificio = ce.id_capacidad_edificio and ce.id_capacidad = c.id_capacidad and c.max_capacidad >= '" + no_of_people + "' and i.id_edificio = e.id_edificio and e.poblacion_edificio = '" + cityId + "' and e.status = 'STATUS_ACTIVE' and e.xml = 'si' group by i.id_edificio, i.id_capacidad_edificio order by i.precio ASC";`

To this:

`string withPriceQueryByAppforavialibity = "select distinct i.id_edificio ,ce.id_capacidad_edificio, i.precio , SUM(i.precio) as base_price, i.disponibilidad, ce.tipo, c.max_capacidad, c.descripcion_capacidad, e.poblacion_edificio, e.provincia_edificio, e.pais_edificio FROM inventario i, capacidad_edificio ce, capacidad c, edificios e WHERE 1=1 and ( i.disponibilidad = -1 ) and i.fecha between '" + date_from + "' and Date_Sub('" + date_to + "',interval 1 Day) and i.id_capacidad_edificio = ce.id_capacidad_edificio and ce.id_capacidad = c.id_capacidad and c.max_capacidad >= '" + no_of_people + "' and i.id_edificio = e.id_edificio and e.poblacion_edificio = '" + cityId + "' and e.status = 'STATUS_ACTIVE' and e.xml = 'si' group by i.id_edificio, i.id_capacidad_edificio order by i.precio ASC";`

and wherever you see this line:

`Convert.ToInt16(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"]) == -1`

Change it to this.

`ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"] == -1`

Please ensure this works

Comment: you saw data table records which i have posted in that "disponibilidad" column is there that column contains diff numbers -1 indicates "onRequest" and other numbers indicates online k.and see the for loops using for loops i am fetching records but its not coming properly

Comment: and ds7 i am getting query result but i am displaying that record through for loops but its not taking the values according to condition

Comment: Which condition is not working? In what way is the result different to what you expect?

Comment: "for (int i = 0; i < ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {"see this for loop and below of that for loop code will fetch the records and display but in that loops some problems are there but i am not getting properly

Comment: every for loops are working but not giving the correct result

Comment: Yes I understand that you are not getting the correct result. Please explain what result you want, and what result you are actually getting so that we can see the difference.

Comment: ok, i have posted data table records wright pls observe the this column "disponibilidad" its contains numbers like -1,5,3 ok i have written two query in my code d7 will written all the records and "daforavialibity" its written only -1 records ok. and i have posted na in that table contains 2 rows -1 so -1 is "OnRequest" so i am seraching the rows by id's ok but "1986" this id records contains -1 so it should display OnRerquest but its writtening online.

Comment: you understand wat i have told now

Comment: Okay, in your database what DataType is `i.disponibilidad`? Is is a string (Char, VarChar, NVarChar etc.) or is it an integer (Int, Integer etc.) please?

Comment: that column contains int

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' its giving error for this line "ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"] == -1"

Comment: Right okay. In that case leave that line as it is. You still need to change the query line though.

Comment: Hang on, why are you even doing this check? Your query should only be returning rows that have -1 in that column so there is no need for the check in the first place. The more I read into your code the more I can see wrong. this will need refractoring or cleaning up in some way. For example this line here `if (ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count == dsavailablity.Tables[0].Rows.Count)` has no `else` clause but it should never be true anyway.

Comment: ya my query is giving result correctly but while checking the condition its returing false values.

Comment: so please give me solution for that/

Comment: i am trying from two days but i am not getting pls help me

Comment: Okay, so can you breakpoint the code there and then type `?Convert.ToInt16(ds7.Tables[0].Rows[i]["disponibilidad"])` into the Immediate Window please? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx

Comment: one more thing tipo column having A,B ok if any one A or B -1 is it possible to convert into -1 only